# Required Designator in C++ 20

Tags: c++, c++20

How can I create a required designator in C++ designated initializer aggregate initialization for structs? Or, put another way, how can I disable default initialization for a struct member?

What I'd like to be able to do is something like this.

```cpp
struct A {
  int x = required;
  int y = 0;
};

A b{.x = 1, .y = 2}; // ok
A a{.x = 1}; // ok
A a{.y = 2}; // error
A a; // error
```

Context: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization#Designated_initializers

Comment: Why not use a constructor if you need to enforce this?

Comment: I want the designated initializer, named argument-like syntax.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure how to make the last one of these fail, but gcc (and apparently only gcc, under `-Wextra`) has a warning option on missing initializers. This gets you... some of the way:

```cpp
struct A {
  int x;
  int y = 0;
};

A a{.x = 1, .y = 2}; // ok
A b{.x = 1};         // ok
A c{.y = 2};         // warning: missing initializer for member 'A::x' 
A d;                 // ok :-(
```

You can get further by wrapping in a type that doesn't provide a default constructor:

```cpp
template <class T>
struct Required {
    T t;
    constexpr Required(T t) : t(t)  { }
    operator T() const { return t; }
};

struct A {
  Required<int> x;
  int y = 0;
};
```

But now the error messages aren't great for:

```
A c{.y = 2};
```

gcc doesn't mention `x`

```
<source>:13:11: error: could not convert '<brace-enclosed initializer list>()' from '<brace-enclosed initializer list>' to 'Required<int>'
   13 | A c{.y = 2};
      |           ^
      |           |
      |           <brace-enclosed initializer list>
```

clang eventually does though:

```
<source>:13:11: error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'Required<int>'
A c{.y = 2};         
          ^
<source>:4:15: note: candidate constructor not viable: requires single argument 't', but no arguments were provided
    constexpr Required(T t) : t(t)  { }
              ^
<source>:2:8: note: candidate constructor (the implicit copy constructor) not viable: requires 1 argument, but 0 were provided
struct Required {
       ^
<source>:2:8: note: candidate constructor (the implicit move constructor) not viable: requires 1 argument, but 0 were provided
<source>:9:17: note: in implicit initialization of field 'x' with omitted initializer
  Required<int> x;
                ^
```

MSVC doesn't either:

```
<source>(13): error C2512: 'Required<int>': no appropriate default constructor available
<source>(13): note: No constructor could take the source type, or constructor overload resolution was ambiguous
```

Unfortunately, relying on the missing-initializer approach (gcc's warning is *by far* the best diagnostic and doesn't make you distort your code) doesn't let you prevent a default constructed `A`. Since, in our infinite wisdom, we decided that this ceases to be an aggregate.

```cpp
struct A {
  A() = delete;
  int x;
  int y = 0;
};
```

That leaves your only option as making `x` `const` (though that in of itself isn't sufficient to catch the missing initializer, still need the warning for that).

Comment: regarding infinite wisdom: is there some paper discussing this, or it was never considered... seems harmless to let that guy be aggregate

Answer (score 0):

You can create multiple constructors for different scenarios like this:

```cpp
struct A {
  int x;
  int y = 0;
  A(int arg_x): x(arg_x){}
  A(int arg_x, int arg_y): x(arg_x), y(arg_y){}
};
```

This will give the exact behaviour you want. Which might not exactly be what you are asking for but can be useful.

Or you can make `x` a `const` like this:

```cpp
struct A {
  const int x;
  int y = 0;
};
```

With this, it looks more similar to what you have asked but now x must be uninitialized and you might not want a const variable in your struct.

Comment: Making it `const` doesn't help - it'd make the `A d;` case fail to compile, but `A c{.y=2};` case would work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you accept double braces for initialization, you can fully customize the designated initializers. You can even allow to exchange the order of `.x` and `.y`, if you want.

```
class A {
public:                                      // allowed constructors
    explicit A(A_x _x) : x(_x.x) {};
    A(A_x _x, A_y _y) : x(_x.x), y(_y.y) {};
    A(A_y _y, A_x _x) : x(_x.x), y(_y.y) {}; // include this line to enable initialization with .y as first and .x as second parameter

    int x;
    int y = 0;

private:                               // repeat constructors with each replaced with ambiguous one to force designated initializer
    explicit A(A_i _i) = delete;       // "same as" first constructor
    A(A_x _x, A_i _i) = delete;        // "same as" second constructor
    A(A_i _i, A_y _y) = delete;        // "same as" second constructor
    A(A_i _i, A_x _x) = delete;        // "same as" third constructor
    A(A_y _y, A_i _i) = delete;        // "same as" third constructor

    struct A_x {
        designated<int> x;             // the name of the member variable is important
    };

    struct A_y {
        designated<int> y;             // the name of the member variable is important
    };


    struct A_i {                       // used to make A_x or A_y ambiguous
        designated<int> i;
    };

                                       // can be moved outside of class
    template<class C>                  // flexible for any member variable type
    class designated {                 // require designated initializer
    public:
        designated(C c) : _c(c) {};    // implicitly converting
        operator C() {return _c;};     // implicitly converting
    private:
        C _c;
    };
};

int main() {
    A a1{{.x = 1}, {.y = 2}};  // ok
    A a2{{.y = 1}, {.x = 2}};  // ok (conditionally, see above how to change)
    A a3{{.x = 1}};            // ok

    A a4{{.y = 2}};            // error (no constructor could take source type)
    A a5;                      // error (no default constructor)
    A a6{};                    // error (no default constructor)
    A a7{{}, {.y = 2}};        // error (no constructor could take source type)
    A a8{{0}, {.y = 2}};       // error (constructor ambiguous)
    A a9{0, {.y = 2}};         // error (no constructor could take source type)
    A a10{{.i = 4}, {.y = 3}}; // error (references a deleted function)
    A a11{{A::A_x{0}};         // error (cannot access private struct)

    A b1({.x = 1}, {.y = 2});  // ok
    A b2({.y = 1}, {.x = 2});  // ok (conditionally, see above how to change)
    A b3({.x = 1});            // ok

    A b4({.y = 2});            // error (no constructor could take source type)
    A b6();                    // error (no default constructor)
    A b7({}, {.y = 2});        // error (no constructor could take source type)
    A b8({0}, {.y = 2});       // error (constructor ambiguous)
    A b9(0, {.y = 2});         // error (no constructor could take source type)
    A b10({.i = 4}, {.y = 3}); // error (references a deleted function)
    A b11({A::A_x{0});         // error (cannot access private struct)
}
```

Comment: A very well-constructed solution, unfortunately it won't scale well.